# Goole Play Console does not rollout update(rollout button clicked)

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

I have a react native app in production on the google play store. I'm trying to release an update to my app on google play console. i've created the aab bundle with an updated version, uploaded it on Release Managment>App releases, went to review and clicked on roll out as everything seemd fine. 
The updated release version, 1.3,  shows on the Release Dashboard, but it's not in the store yet. Perhaps google is takin time to check it, but if so, where does it tell me that it's on it's way to the store?

[image: my app releases- production track]

AS you can see it says i have a release that hasn't been rolled out. But i did click on roll out for that release. And i can't go to release because it says:

"You should either add a new APK or deactivate an existing APK to create a new release."

which makes sense if the 1.3 release is on its way to the store, but how can i know?

I just tried updating again to 1.4 so you can see what happens:

[image]

From here i  deactivate old version, click 'Save' and 'Review', then on the next screen 'Start Rollout To Production'(percentage of release is 100%). But again, is it really on it's way to production?

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have updated the build number not just the version release name.

Comment: I've updated both versionCode and versionName in the gradle. is that what you meant?

Comment: after deactivation of the old version you have to upload or import new apk with new build version number and be aware also that google roll out will not take effect immediately.

Answer (score 0):

So the update got to the store, but it would really be helpfull if there was some sort of way to see the state of the upload.